# sum( array, 1) giving 'nan' in Python

Tags: python, sockets, file-io, multidimensional-array, physics

First of all i know nan stands for "not a number" but I am not sure how i am getting an invalid number in my code. What i am doing is using a python script that reads a file for a list of vectors (x,y,z) and then converts it to a long array of values, but if i don't use the file and i make a for loop that generates random numbers i don't get any 'nan's.

After this i am using Newtons law of gravity to calculate the pos of stars, F= GMm/r^2 to calculate positions and then that data gets sent through a socket server to my c# visualizing software that i developed for watching simulations. Unfortuanately my python script that does the calculating has only but been troublesome to get working.

```
    poslist = []
    plist = []
    mlist = []
    lineList = []
    coords = []

    with open("Hyades Vectors.txt", "r") as text_file:
        content = text_file.readlines()
        #remove /n
        for i in range(len(content)):
            for char in "\n":
                line = content[i].replace(char,"")
            lineList.append(line)
        lines = array(lineList)

        #split "   " within each line
        for i in range(len(lines)):
            coords.append(lines[i].split("   "))
        coords = array(coords)

        #convert coords string to integer
        for i in range(len(coords)):
            x = np.float(coords[i,0])
            y = np.float(coords[i,1])
            z = np.float(coords[i,2])
            poslist.append((x,y,z))

    pos = array(poslist)
```

quite often it is sending nan's after the second time going through this loop

```
        vcm = sum(p)/sum(m) #velocity of centre mass
        p = p-m*vcm #make total initial momentum equal zero
        Myr = 8.4
        dt = 1
        pos = pos-(p/m)*(dt/2.) #initial half-step

        finished = False
        while not finished:         # or NBodyVis.Oppenned() == False

            r = pos-pos[:,newaxis] #all pairs of star-to-star vectors
            for n in range(Nstars):
                r[n,n] = 1e6 #otherwise the self-forces are infinite
            rmag = sqrt(sum(square(r),-1)) #star-to star scalar distances
            F = G*m*m[:,newaxis]*r/rmag[:,:,newaxis]**3 # all force pairs

            for n in range(Nstars):
                F[n,n] = 5  # no self-forces
            p = p+sum(F,1)*dt           #sum(F,1) is where i get a nan!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

            pos -= (p/m)*dt

            if Time <= 0:
                finished = True
            else:
                Time -= 1
```

What am i doing wrong?????? I don't fully understand nans but i can't have them if my visualizing software is to read a nan, as for then nothing will apear for visuals. I know that the error is sum(F,1) I went and printed everything through until i got a nan and that is where, but how is it getting a nan from summing. Here is what part of the text file looks like that i am reading:

```
    51.48855   4.74229   -85.24499
    121.87149   11.44572   -140.79644
    59.81673   68.8417   18.76767
    31.95567   37.23007   6.59515
    29.81066   34.76371   6.18374
    41.35333   49.52844   14.12314
    32.10481   38.46982   7.96628
    48.13239   60.4019   37.45474
    26.37793   34.53385   15.9054
    76.02468   103.98826   25.96607
    51.52072   71.17618   32.09829
```

please help

Comment: There's a lot of code here, so it's hard to know where to start, especially without seeing your traceback. Have a look at how to make an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and see if you can pare the question down. Then add the traceback as well.

Comment: the part F = G*m*m[:,newaxis]*r/rmag[:,:,newaxis]**3 # all force pairs is where the nans come, i tested by printing each section and rmag[:,:,newaxis]**3 is the main section and usually prints looking like:  [[3.2343423423e30,2.3242342423e29, 5.3234423423e30]                                                                                 [nan,nan,nan]                                                                 [nan,nan,nan]                                                             ...

Comment: My original comment still applies: *edit* your question to remove all the irrelevant parts, and include your *full* traceback

Comment: sure i will, i know what you mean

Comment: there is still a fair amount of code but i think it looks better now